# Typescript, how to share a bound utility function between two classes that add items to a Map

Tags: typescript, union-types

Let's say I have two classes and I'd like them to share a utility function between them. That utility class accesses a property that's a Map of a type of object. The object type stored in the map is different for each class. The function is called bounded with the instance of the class calling it, and is passed as an argument the object it should add into the map. An over-simplified version might look like this.

```
interface fooItem {
    name: string
}

interface barItem {
    name: string
    compact: boolean
}

function setItems(this: Foo | Bar, item: fooItem | barItem) {
    // Error here on 'item' arg
    this.items.set(item.name, item); 
}

class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.items = new Map();
    }
    items: Map<string, fooItem>;
    setItems = setItems.bind(this);
}

class Bar {
    constructor() {
        this.items = new Map();
    }
    items: Map<string, barItem>;
    setItems = setItems.bind(this);
}
```

[Link to this code on typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#)

This code throws a compiler error

```
Argument of type 'fooItem | barItem' is not assignable to parameter of type 'barItem'.
  Property 'compact' is missing in type 'fooItem' but required in type 'barItem'.
```

The intention is for an object to only ever be used with the class its associated with, but I understand how the compiler can't guarantee they are paired.

**What's the proper typescript syntax to let the compiler know item will be type `fooItem` when this is type `Foo`, and vice versa?**

Comment: A generic function like `function setItems<T extends { name: string }>(this: { items: Map<string, T> },  item: T ) { this.items.set(item.name, item); }` would work for that, but you'll find that the result of `setItems.bind(this)` will not be strongly typed enough for you to use it.  You might need some manual annotations or assertions to get farther.

Answer (score 0):

It would work better if you use an explicit binding function instead of the stock `bind`, for example:

```
interface NamedItem {
  name: string
}

interface HasNamedMap<T extends NamedItem> {
  items: Map<string, T>;
}

function setItems<T extends NamedItem>(obj: HasNamedMap<T>): (item: T) => void {
  return function(item: T) {
    obj.items.set(item.name, item);
  }
}
```

This way specific "item" types can be correctly inferred:

```
class Foo {
  items: Map<string, fooItem> = new Map();
  setItems = setItems(this); // inferred as (item: fooItem) => void
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHJwLYQCYElIbIDeAUMsiJhAFzIDOYUoA5iQL4kmiSyIoAScOuizYAsnAAOAHgAqyCAA9IIbHTRU8BAHzEyyYATq0JMhkxDMANMlnaA3O04wAriARhgAexD0IYfAgMOjkFZQhVdREcQIxtAAovACMAK1pBYU1TOW0ASlp4wyDaWVzkAF5dADcvYGw9cih-FyhfV3dPH0KCErLScnJklIA6IuDhun9uoOHKLBsx3MdyDg4SAHp1zm5oeCRkGC8vWIaKKlpzFn1Dr1kACxZaEBcMJOgnLnBdvmQkuCgTv0zlgLowruQ-lB7o9fkcADYQOAgD4kBBwoTqABiR1OY2MyGyl0sNhusV05QoEAA7gSpPElvpJgEjBU-MygnR4mAHnQGWs0RjkAAhf7kIF4kxSaRE6y-f5k1kgam0yT05Zs2LqClMzVcnl8zjxJU07Feem5Cb+XVEOY0ZAAIjg9pJR2hlloAEY2EsBuRNsgvABrEhG5UiqDmy3s4LxG3nB1OmyQt3MWiMFwQb32P3rAPBkPG5CmyM6oyx220R32rPIf3wYBwgth-4lq1lohJI6Vp01utwBucIA)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the constraint you're asking for, I'd make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function like the following:

```
function setItems<T extends { name: string }>(
    this: { items: Map<string, T> },
    item: T
) {
    this.items.set(item.name, item); // okay
}
```

But you'll find if you try to `bind()` it to `this`, the compiler will forget that the `item` is narrower than `{name: string}` and you'll get something too weakly typed to be useful by itself.

You'd then need to manually widen `setItems` to a concrete type for each class:

```
// separate var with annotation
const fooSetItems: (this: Foo, item: fooItem) => void = setItems;
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.items = new Map();
    }
    items: Map<string, fooItem>;
    setItems = fooSetItems.bind(this);
}


class Bar {
    constructor() {
        this.items = new Map();
    }
    items: Map<string, barItem>;

    // same var with assertion
    setItems = (setItems as (this: Bar, item: barItem) => void).bind(this);
}
```

This works, but is more complicated than I like.

---

A suggestion instead: since you're already attaching function-valued properties to each instance of `Foo` and `Bar` instead of using the prototype, I'd give up on `this` parameters entirely and just use a plain function:

```
const bindSetItems =
    <N extends { name: string }>(ctx: { items: Map<string, N> }) =>
        (item: N) => ctx.items.set(item.name, item);

class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.items = new Map();
    }
    items: Map<string, fooItem>;
    setItems = bindSetItems(this);
}

class Bar {
    constructor() {
        this.items = new Map();
    }
    items: Map<string, barItem>;
    setItems = bindSetItems(this);
}
```

This behaves the same, but instead of messing with `this`, it just uses currying instead of prototypical inheritance to get the job done.

---

Hopefully one of those works for you.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAhgezQSUgW2QbwFgAoZM5EOHCALmQGcwpQBzE85ADzpAFccARtBIBfEiVCRYiFALhRsEPEVLlK1Oo2Yg2qsgjQ4ADojB0BGADYQ4IUeOLqI9E0mQAhUABMC7cjF4QBDBgNBAGCDBFHHoAHgAVZAhOSBAvegIKKloGJlZkEQA+AAo-DjIwAAtgejp8ZGBcWuQAWTgjWK1WABpkeMKC7rLyxqU6eOGASl89cqqagDpRmIX6SOLlhade5cmAbmGxYgcOAHpTiJMoOEhkADd5ZAB3RsrkWxA0MBvQu1mDECMVAYADKkWizWK82aADEMDtcHR0FhcNMALwDO5oYA+NERKJNA7-SxwegZOFoGblcgArS8YJoKDFaYqanU6FLJrIPEgCBPVrtZlEtkFYYcZbNNodLo6XrI6KFYVstYEpQZPHIsGqlYCbxQ6r0faHBzDBAkskeR6stm0pj0sCM5lUkXkDkS7kUPkCoxCsXkI4iiV0KWdPKy5ByBS4RUnNnnBjZe6PF5Vd5k6AhMJ+sgqiEe4q5rmk5D6mp0dzyBFjCPyaLozHYryTBa6tKlw1KshHezHRzZFwyZAABRJoBhgQQM1NYSBra8WrzaOzyFiADkkikIGkMvUnJowywCiVgtxMkHvaHtCxequBiJ68uOBtEchV-XkCfOWrVutNtsGqiRKmua5IYM61K2lA9qOiyj6ugaX4xB6vL8lKvqzBwAZsueIYytewIokoMYYeQhZqh6c4Lk07ZGrM3a9hwZqkhkFZQOB5SQdBTKwSR7IIe6PJemhtEilh1I4e0l49DWUZEZ25RkUheKUeC1HQiJ-oOCIQA)